# xCode 4.3.1 always jump to main function when having exception

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

My XCode (v4.3.1) always jump to main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

whenever i have an exception.
What's wrong with my xCode? How can I fix this issue?
Please help me!

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in `objc_exception_throw`, that'll let you stop right where it's thrown.

Comment: Thank Isaksson. It solved my problem, after following this: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/68421

Comment: @toandk: please accept Joachim's answer below so others will know this topic is closed.

Answer (score 1):

XCode will sometimes not stop quite where you want it when an exception is thrown. If you want to know exactly where it's *thrown*, you can set a breakpoint in `objc_exception_throw` and have it halt right at the `@throw` line.

As a bonus if you're using multiple projects, if you add that breakpoint once to `Global Breakpoints`, it will work in all projects.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your Xcoode. Depend on types of exception, some exception will jump to main when the app crash.