# stringByAppendingString nil argument error in landscape but not portrait

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation

For the following code in an iPad application:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.domain.com/file.xml";
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request startSynchronous];
```

I'm getting a stringByAppendingString nil argument error. The issue is that this error is only thrown when the app is started in landscape orientation, not portrait.

Not sure if it's relevant, but the error is thrown from the main thread, while the code above is running in another thread.

Where should I be looking for bugs here? I've started with hunting for occasions where stringByAppendingString might be used, but simply can't find any (doesn't mean they're not there though - I may just not understand how this is being used behind the scenes). There's nothing that differs between the landscape and portrait launches, apart from the orientation of a splash UIView, which seems to be working fine. Also, the URL I'm using is valid as far as I can tell (needless to say, the URL in the example is representative, but not the actual URL).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try debugging using this and see if you can get a location of the crash; http://stackoverflow.com/a/9680654/477878

Comment: Thanks Joachim - that was just what was needed. Figured out the answer using this approach! Hadn't come across this before, so extremely helpful.

Comment: Can't post the answer for another 7 hours, apparently, so here it is in the comments for now: thanks to Joachim's suggestion of setting a symbolic breakpoint on obc_exception_throw, I figured out that: 1. the app is always launched in portrait, and then willAnimateRotation... is called (which, it turns out, is standard - silly me)
 2. the existing implementation of willAnimateRotation... assumed that all content was loaded, and so was calling a content management method which passed a nil argument (since content wasn't yet loaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joachim's suggestion of setting a symbolic breakpoint on obc_exception_throw, I figured out that: 1. the app is always launched in portrait, and then willAnimateRotation... is called (which, it turns out, is standard - silly me) 2. the existing implementation of willAnimateRotation... assumed that all content was loaded, and so was calling a content management method which passed a nil argument (since content wasn't yet loaded).

So, lesson here is that app ALWAYS launches in portrait, and then any loaded views are auto rotated afterwards if the device is in landscape.